# Is there a way to wipe complete GTK cache?

Tags: cache, gtk, maintenance

GTK remembers a lot of stuffs like the last folder I used when you try to "Save As" in any application, the size of the "Open File" window. Is there a way to remove that?

I have cleared:

```
rm -f "${HOME}/.local/share/recently-used.xbel*"
rm -f "${HOME}/.local/share/user-places.xbel*"
```

but that doesn't seem to be do it. Is there a way to clear the entire GTK ecosystem cache? I have a cleanup script that always restores my Linux box to its original state and I am trying to improve it.

Comment: Did you check whether your commands _removed_ the files?

Comment: @grawity, oops it doesn't - I added quotes for bash strings *without* testing. Do I have to avoid quoting `*` like `rm -f "${HOME}"/.local/share/recently-used.xbel*` for the expansion to work? Sorry I am still learning shell scripting. Also, hopefully that solves the issue :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The history is not wiped because your command doesn't even delete the files. (And the `-f` option hides all error messages that would have shown up otherwise.)

In shell, wildcards are only expanded when they are *not* quoted at all. You would have to use either:

```
rm -f "$HOME/.local/share/recently-used.xbel"*

rm -f "$HOME"/.local/share/recently-used.xbel*

rm -f ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel*
```